# Executing the Chaged Ouput tupe Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am having a issue need some help .

I have Create a Test Project  in Visual studio .
now as the client requirement i have to also add a  class with Main function  to convert it as Console Application so i have changed the Ouput type of Project to ConsoleApplication from Class Library. Now the issue is that when ever i press F5 to execute the Project its always run test cases but i need to execute the Console File .

can anyone help me out of this

Comment: uh.. what..? I understood, like, 45% of what you wrote. Please fix the punctation bit. Also, please say more about what you see/have now and what you need to achieve. It is very brief now and forces to guess what you have in mind.

Comment: right-click the project in Solution Explorer and click "Set as Startup Project"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have set the test project as "startup project" anyway. So please **right-click on the main console project in the "Solution Explorer" and select "Set as startup project".** Then press F5 to get your desired output ;)

Comment: no actually i have a test project.  <br/> and in that project i have added a console file. <Br /> so now i have a console and test application in same application.<br/> and i want to execute the console file with main function in Vs 2010 . <br /> i have also changed the output type to Console but when i run the project in Vs 2010 it execute the test cases ..